# NetInfo not working perfectly in react-native (often not updatings)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am developing sample application in react-native. i am creating Netinfo file after i am calling like component another screen.

Where should i place this component to get it into all screens?

Main problem is status not always changing when networking changes.

if i select offline showing red textview, and then i am choose online showing green Textview. Again if i change  tooffline it's not updated.

Here this is my sample code:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View, Text, NetInfo, Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

function MiniOfflineSign() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.offlineContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.offlineText}>No Internet Connection</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

class OfflineNotice extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    isConnected: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
  }

  handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
    if (isConnected) {
      this.setState({ isConnected });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isConnected });
    }
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isConnected) {
      return (
         <View style={styles.offlineContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.offlineText}>No Internet Connection</Text>
         </View>
         );
    }else{
       return (
         <View style={[styles.offlineContainer, {backgroundColor:'green'}]}>
          <Text style={styles.offlineText}>Internet Connection Is Availiable</Text>
         </View>
         );

    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  offlineContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#b52424',
    height: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 30
  },
  offlineText: { color: '#fff' }
});

export default OfflineNotice;
```

Comment: You should really either read your question few times before posting it, or ask someone for help in English. That was really messy and difficult to figure out what you're trying to say. That's still not good, but I gave up.

Comment: Thank you mr@JamesZ